# WatiN, filling an input by CSS selector does not work

Tags: css-selectors, web-scraping, watin

I am trying to fill an input matching a given CSS selector using WatiN.
Here is a code sample:

```
public ActionResult Do(WebScraper webScraper)
        {
            var target = webScraper.Browser.Element(Find.BySelector(TargetSelector));
            if (target == null)
            {
                return ActionResult.Failure(string.Format("No element found matching selector '{0}'.", TargetSelector));
            }

            target.SetAttributeValue("value", Value);
            return ActionResult.Success();
        }
```

Testing with a TargetSelector being "#someID". Did inspect the page right before this is executed and I can see a `<input id="someID" ... ></input>`

Getting an error that looks like this:

> Could not find Element Tag matching Criteria: Selector = '#someID'

Thanks,

Comment: I have never used watin, but could it be that you need to pass `someID` instead of `#someID`?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Find.BySelector expects a JQuery/CSS style selector. Which means prefixes '#' and '.' should stand for id and class.

Comment: If you have the ID, why don't you do a Find.ById()?    Also, in Selenium for CSSSelectors you don't use the # - I don't know about WatiN but you should try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Elements.Filter, gave the expected result... Using that instead.

```
//var target = webScraper.Browser.Element(Find.BySelector(TargetSelector));
var target = webScraper.Browser.Elements.Filter(Find.BySelector(TargetSelector)).FirstOrDefault();
```